# jquery timer or countdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, timer, counter

I need to display a waiting time, say in minutes and seconds or may be in hours, minutes and seconds format to the user. Is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this site:

[Jquery CountDown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

I hope its what you are looking for. There are both with and without seconds and minutes.

EDIT!

The code could look like:

```
$('#noDaysSeconds').countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HM'});
```

If your dont want it to state "Hours" and "Minutes" under the numbers then use this example:

```
$('#minimal').countdown({until: liftoffTime, compact: true, 
format: 'HM', description: ''});
```

//Gerner

Comment: but i dont want days.. I just want hours: minutes : seconds or minutes:seconds

Comment: When you enter the site, then try and click the tab "Formats 1".
The first example is only, hours, minutes and seconds.

If your import it right, as the explain, i guess your could just write:

`$(selector).countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HM'});`

HM for HoursMinutes.. I would try and write s or ss and the end for seconds. :) This way your can modify it to fit your purpose..

EDIT!
Just found the code your looking for:

Hours - minutes - Seconds
`$('#noDays').countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS'});`

`$('#noDaysSeconds').countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HM'});`

Comment: thanks Andres, and can I set the Hours minutes and seconds too?!